# .htaccess redirect with forward slash

Tags: .htaccess

My index.php file is inside s directory like

https://example.com/s/index.php

I have .htaccess file like below

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?random=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?random=$1&java=$2 [L]
```

its working fine and redirecting properly

like https://example.com/s/15091722/yes

But I want add one more variable like

https://example.com/s/15091722/yes/152030

so I have tried like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?random=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?random=$1&java=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?random=$1&java=$2&u=$3 [L]
```

But its giving me error called not found. I think I am missing something but not getting idea.
Let me know if anyone here can help me for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: The example you posted should already work with the example URLs given (if your previous example worked). Also consider making the regex more restrictive - to match only the specific format of URL being passed. eg. You appear to be passing a number, but you are checking for _anything_ in the regex. By making the regex more restrictive you can avoid the additional filesystem checks (`RewriteCond` directives) which would be more concise and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example doesn't work for me at all, see https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=d6d58756-3171-4ace-99d3-354694f52b24. Your path consists of three segments (**s**, **15091722** and **yes**). But in your rule you only asking for one or two of them to match.

What you basically need to do is to extend your rule by more path segments eg: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=edd7cb32-be87-49ac-ac72-562922bd2a49

As you may notice, splitting paths like that could get messi very soon. So maybe it should be worth it thinking about redirecting everything to index.php and splitting path segments dynamically with your programming language afterwords

Comment: Thanks for your answer but s is directory where index.php file is located

Comment: "s is directory where index.php file is located" - and, importantly, that is also where the `.htaccess` file would seem to be located.